# Creating an array from another class

Tags: java

I have a `WordFreq` class that has a `processLines` method that creates an array from the `WordCount` class. I have other lines of the `processLines` method access `WordCount` without an issue.

I have:

```
public class WordCount{

    private String word;
    private int count;

    public WordCount(String w){
        word = w;
        count = 0;
    }
```

followed by the class methods:

```
public class WordFreq extends Echo {

    String words, file;
    String[] wordArray;
    WordCount[] search;
```

WordFreq is passed a text file(handled in Echo) and a string of words to search for.

```
public WordFreq(String f, String w){
    super(f);
    words = w;
}

public void processLine(String line){
    file = line;
    wordArray = file.split(" ");

    // here is where I have tried several methods to initialize the search
    // array with the words in the words variable, but I can't get the
    // compiler to accept any of them.

    search = words.split(" ");

    StringTokenizer w = new StringTokenizer(words);
    search = new WordCount[words.length()];

    for(int k =0; k < words.length(); k++){
        search[k] = w.nextToken();
```

I tried a few other things that didn't work. I tried casting what was to the right of `search[k]` = to `WordCount`, but it won't get past the compiler. I keep getting incompatible types.

```
Required: WordCount found: java.lang.String.
```

I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String[] tokens = words.split(" ");
search = new WordCount[tokens.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
    search[i] = new WordCount(tokens[i]);
}
```

The problem with your first attempt is that `words.split(" ")` results in a `String` array; you can't assign to a `WordCount` array variable. The problem with the second method is that `words.length()` is the number of *characters* in `words`, not the number of tokens. You could probably make your second method work by using `w.countTokens()` in place of `words.length()`, but, again, you need to convert each `String` returned by `w.nextToken()` to a `WordCount` object.

Comment: That did the trick! I ended up with some run time errors using the .length() in some other methods. I probably would have gotten stuck there for a little bit if you hadn't pointed that out. I've got the program functioning properly now. Thank you.